# php interpreter and superglobals

Tags: php, arguments, superglobals

first of all, I'm a French student, so excuse me for my poor English
level.

We are currently developing a web server (C++) and I must develop the CGI execution
part, more exactly : The PHP CGI part.

When a user ask a .php page on our server, we fork/pipe and call the /usr/bin/php
interpreter. For example :

$ /usr/bin/php index.php

Now, we can save the result in a buffer (generated html code of index.php), and I can send
this content to the client. It's working for a simple script without any variable.

However, lot of php script use some superglobals like $_GET and $_POST.
My problem is : How can I give to the php interpreter this argument ?

Example : How can I set this $_POST variable in the aim to save "Hello world" in 
our buffer ?

```
<?php

echo $_POST['text'];

?>
```

Thank you for your future responses.

cordially

Comment: "so excuse me for my poor English level" - at least you do speak some English ;)

Comment: Bonjour, the reply is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/942976

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass GET and POST data to the php executable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/942976/how-to-pass-get-and-post-data-to-the-php-executable)

Comment: That solution explains only GET requests, however.

Answer (score 4):

CGI programs expect POST data on `stdin`. and GET data in the `QUERY_STRING` environment variable.

Answer (score 3):

You have to set some environment variables:

- `REQUEST_METHOD=POST` to tell PHP that it needs to handle a POST request
- `CONTENT_LENGTH=1234` to tell PHP how many bytes it will receive as raw POST data (in this case 1234 bytes)
- `HTTP_CONTENT_LENGTH` basically the same as `CONTENT_LENGTH`. Better set this too so that it will work better with the various PHP versions/configurations.
- `CONTENT_TYPE=application/x-www-form-urlencoded` is the HTTP Content-Type header

You get the right values for these variables from the HTTP header.

You also need a bidirectional pipe to the PHP process to send the raw POST data to it's STDIN. I assume you are already receiving the script output from PHP.

As long as you handle a normal browser request, you don't need to know any more details. Otherwise, if the POST data comes directly from your server, use the CONTENT_TYPE above and url-encode the variables:

- `REQUEST_METHOD=POST`
- `CONTENT_LENGTH=16`
- `HTTP_CONTENT_LENGTH=16`
- `CONTENT_TYPE=application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

STDIN data:
`test=Hello+world`

For GET requests you change `REQUEST_METHOD=GET` and leave away the other variables. In either case you can pass the query string via the `QUERY_STRING` environment variable.

Comment: Thank you so much for your responses.

I tried to respect your advices but ... POST requests not works for me :(

I use 2 binary. The first one load the environment variables : http://pastebin.com/XbaaxRWF 

The other one call the php interpreter : http://pastebin.com/XYLv1yjV

Between this 2 binary, we have à pipe in the aim to tranfert all informations.

Have you got an idea ? 

The GET method works, so thanks to you =D

Have a nice day.

Comment: I had no time to have a look at your source code, but instead of running PHP try to start a shell script (or similar) that writes the environment variables and STDIN data to a text file and check that data. You could also just run `set` and `cat` alone and should get the info back on STDOUT. That way you can be sure that it's not PHP that refuses to work because one of it's security restrictions...